# What are the odds of picking one outcome out of three, if you have two attempts and the one you pick is removed from the pool?

Tags: probability, monty-hall

*Edited for (hopefully) clarity.*

There are three cards on the table facedown, two with the [o] symbol and one with [x]. You must find [x] to "win" and you have two attempts. If you do not find the [x] after your first try, the card you picked is removed and there are now only two cards. One [o] and one [x].

First attempt:

[o] [o] [x]

1/3 chance, 33.3%

Second attempt (assuming first one was unsuccessful):

[o] [x]

1/2 chance, 50%

What is the final probability of picking the [x]?

I thought that Chance AB = Chance A * Chance B, but that would be 1/3 * 1/2 = 1/6, which seems way too low to be correct.

On the other hand 1/3 + 1/2 = 5/6

I also further confused myself by trying to calculate the odds of *not* picking the [x] using both above methods.

2/3 * 1/2 = 1/3, which is obviously incorrect, since it does not add up to a 1 if you sum the 1/6 from above

But then 2/3 + 1/2 = 7/6 ???? yeah...

Obviously I have no idea what I am doing, can someone please untangle me? Thank you.

Comment: See the [Monty Hall Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem).

Comment: This is hard to follow.  What are the rules exactly?  These problems tend to come down to clarity and what you have written is far from clear.

Comment: @lulu Edited to make it clear, I hope.

Comment: Ok...so you get to look at two cards out of three.  Hence your chances of success are $\frac 23$.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with the Monty Hall problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're close but I think you are conflating two different ideas. Namely, if $A$ and $B$ are independent then it is true that $P(AB) = P(A)P(B)$ however this is NOT the probability we want to calculate. We want to calculate the probability that we get our desired outcome. Let's call this event $X$. So we can get $X$ on our first try, let's call this event $C$, or we can get $X$ on our second try, let's call this event $D$. We now note that $X = C \text{ or } D$, also written as $X = C\cup D$, hence what we really want to find is $P(C\cup D)$. There are a few easy ways going about this so I'll go over one such way. We first note that since $C$ and $D$ can't occur at the same time then (this is called the property of mutual additivity) then we have that
$$P(C \cup D) = P(C) + P(D)$$
You correctly pointed out that $P(C) = \frac{1}{3}$ so it begs the question, what is $P(D)$? Informally, for $D$ to occur we have to fail the first guess and get the correct outcome on the second. Hence $$P(D) = P(\text{first guess is incorrect})(\text{second is correct}) = \frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{3}$$
and hence
$$P(C \cup D) = P(C) + P(D) = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} = \frac{2}{3}$$

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer! However, I am confused by the final equation. If P(C)=1/3 and P(D)=1/3, why is P(C∪D) 1/2+1/3 ?

Comment: @KardNails Sorry about that, it was a typo on my part. The answer has been updated

Answer (score 0):

You could find the complement of failing on both tries,

hence $1 - \frac23\frac12 = \frac23$